# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\exec()

Tags: laravel

Please help me. The website works fine in the local host, but it is having error in the C panel. How to solve?
the path is:
app/config/app.php

[image]

Comment: this is a very wrong way of asking questions on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Process Component` of Symfony that is already in Laravel

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
```

inside your `elcdetails` use

```
$macAddr = new Process('getmac');
$macAddr->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$macAddr->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($macAddr;
}

//or whatever you want to do with the output. 

echo $macAddr->getOutput();
```

note that, if you are trying to get the client mac address, short answer is you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

From your image, I'm supposing you defined the `public function exec()` function somewhere above  or below in your controller. You cannot reference to it that way since its a method in your controller class.

So change it to this instead. `$macAddr = $this->exec('getmac');`